# % Complete based off dates

Tags: google-sheets

I have a project start date and end date. I want to create a formula that says looking at todays date, here is what % we are into the project. Any way to do this via Google sheets?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier than you think. You can do arithmetic operations on dates. You may need to tweak formatting, but this should work:

```
  |     A      |     B     |
----------------------------
1 | start      | end       |
2 |   1/3/2017 | 5/31/2017 |
```

Assuming your start date is in A2, and your end date is in B2...

The difference between your dates can be expressed as `=B2-A2`.

The difference between your start date and the current date can be expressed as `=TODAY()-A2`.

Using the division of the two will give you the ratio: `=(TODAY()-A2)/(B2-A2)`. (Don't forget the parentheses, otherwise you'll have an order of operations problem.) Then it's just a question of formatting your output as a percentage. (If you want to shortcut it and not worry about formatting, simply multiply the result by 100.)